# How to implement the Greatest Common Divisor in Xilinx ? [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm trying to implement a simple GCD algorithm with VHDL language but i get this error "ERROR:HDLCompiler:981: Non-static loop limit exceeded".

So, How the while statement can work without the error above? and if it's not adaptable with xilinx 14.7 with what statement i can replace it?

```
signal a,b,GCD: integer;

a<=100; --example of a
b<=50; --example of b
while NOT (a*b=0) loop
if a>b then
a<=a-b;
else
b<=b-a;
end if;
end loop;
if a=0 then --result
GCD<=b; 
else GCD<=a; 
end if;
```

Thank you,

Comment: a. Not a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), b. A synthesis error, while loops aren't required to be supported for synthesis and where supported are bounded to a low number of iterations (the sequence of statements is duplicated for each value of the condition expression, you haven't shown types), c.  Signal assignment won't work the way you show here, a signal is never updated while a process is active. d. Use a for loop with an if statement conditionally executing an exit statement, e. Your algorithm is value specific and f. simulate first.

Comment: See [Lesson 93 - Example 63: GCD Algorithm - VHDL while Statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMSaYhD1GkM) on Youtube. (There's a follow on Lesson 94 leading on to real hardware design).

Comment: The companion website for Pong Chu's book [RTL Hardware Design Using VHDL](http://academic.csuohio.edu/chu_p/rtl/rtl_hardware.html) has an example VHDL implementation code listing (list_12_06_07_08_gc.vhd) and Chapter 12 slides for a VHDL GCD implementation. 12.4 GCD Circuit in the book has a shorter discourse than found in the Haskell/Hanna book **Digital Design Using Digilent FPGA Boards VHDL/Active-HDL Edition** (the videos linked above are derived from.)

Comment: *Please*, indent your code.